# Editing an attribute of a reference file without affecting its other attributes

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to edit this particular Camera's node - Film Gate in my scene.
However while doing so, I was given the following error `The attribute 'main_camera01:main_cameraShape.horizontalFilmAperture' is locked or connected and cannot be modified` and `The attribute 'main_camera01:main_cameraShape.verticalFilmAperture' is locked or connected and cannot be modified`

These 2 particular attributes are highlighted in yellow with some connections and the camera is from a referenced file.

I tried something like - `cmds.setAttr('camera01:cameraShape.horizontalFilmAperture', lock=0)` to unlock the attribute, however I got back the same error. Is there anyway in which I can tweak this Film Gate attribute without affecting its other attribute connections?

Answer (score 0):

Yellow means you have connection that means setAttr with lock won't work there. You need to use disconnectAttr. cmds.setAttr('your_source_object.attribute', 'camera01:cameraShape.horizontalFilmAperture'). But in this case I seriously think that you have a reference. In that case story will be different.

Comment: Yes, the cameras are from a reference file

Comment: How would you break the reference and keep the camera in maya scene along with the namespace from the reference maya file ?